# Symfony Serializer empty objects

Tags: symfony, serialization

I need the serializer to produce an empty object. Normally I would just do

`json_encode(new stdClass()) --> '{}'`

but the symfony serializer does

```
$this->get('serializer')->serialize(new  \stdClass(), 'json')) --> '[]'
```

I guess this is because the serializer first normalizes my data to an array, which is in this case empty.

Is there a way to get back json_encode default behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly call `encode` method:

```
$this->get('serializer')->encode(new \StdClass(), 'json')
```

Comment: This does the job if the response is only the standard object. (I guess it just does json_encode()?) But in reality I first fetch some objects with doctrine and then "mix" them with some default values. So my new stdClass() is just a part of the final json. And serializing the doctrine objects with json_encode() does not work.

Comment: I think the only way is to write your own or extend existing normalizer. You need to return object as is if it is an instance of stdClass.